# Is there a difference between a staircase made by a monster and a staircase found under a rock?

Tags: stardew-valley

Do stairs caused by different things in the mines have different chances for things? For example are monster stairs more likely to lead to more monsters or better loot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Any refference?